# Rendered output and markdown views in Suggested Edits

Tags: bug, edits

I have noticed weird behaviour in the Suggested Edits review queue.

Usually I am working in the *Rendered output* view. I review an edit, the site remembers my preference and displays the next edit in the *Rendered output* view. Everything works as expected until I review an edit that changes only tags. At that point, the the next edit is shown in the *Markdown* view.

It is a minor inconvenience if it happens once, but if it happens more times it becomes little annoying. Is it a bug or is there any reason for this?

Comment: You should always be using the markdown view when reviewing suggested edits. There are a lot of changes that can be made which will not show up in the rendered view.